# Is it safe to delete Fabric contents in ~/Library/Caches in iOS APP

Tags: ios, caching, twitter-fabric, google-fabric

There're 2 folders in ~/Library/Caches in our iOS APP:

```
com.crashlytics.data
io.fabric.sdk.ios.data
```

It seems that they're used by Fabric?

I want to add a feature to delete all contents in the Caches folder, and I'm wondering if it's safe to delete these 2 folders?

If I delete the 2 folders when APP is running, what will happen if there're crashes in APP? Will the crash reports still be sent to Fabric?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Are these folders using >5MB space? The answer, without having any facts, is almost certainly "no".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todd from Fabric here. It is not safe to delete these programmatically as they contain our crash report data. The folder Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/ is where crashes are uploaded from when your app relaunches. Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that we can never clear out **anything** in this folder?  I've got build cache going back over a year and the entire "builds" folder is now over 38GB.   I would love to be able to clean out the stuff in here that I no longer need.

Answer (score 1):

As per Apple Docs:

> Put data cache files in the **Library/Caches**/ directory. Cache data can be used for any data that needs to persist longer than temporary data, but not as long as a support file. Generally speaking, the application does not require cache data to operate properly, but it can use cache data to improve performance. Examples of cache data include (but are not limited to) database cache files and transient, downloadable content. Note that the system may delete the **Caches/** directory to free up disk space, so your app must be able to re-create or download these files as needed. [(c)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

So it means, that these folders can be removed even without any additional features in you app. Feel free to do it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I read this apple doc before posting this question. And I know the folders are recreated after app restart. What I worry is "If I delete the 2 folders when APP is running, what will happen if there're crashes in APP? Will the crash reports still be sent to Fabric?"